# How to order by filtered relation count in Prisma

Tags: typescript, express, prisma

Here is my prisma Schema:

```
model Release {
  id                String       @id @default(uuid())
  owner             User         @relation(fields: [ownerId], references: [id])
  ownerId           String
  artistName        String?
  description       String?
  image             String?
  isDeployed        Boolean      @default(false)
  maxNumMints       Int?
  mintPrice         Decimal?
  royaltyPercentage Float?
  releaseType       ReleaseType?
  title             String?
  tracks            Track[]
  genres             Genre[]
}

model Genre {
  id      String    @id @default(uuid())
  name    String
  releases Release[]
}
```

I need to write a query that returns all genres in a similar format

```
    {
    "name": "Pop",
    "id": "ccda198f-3384-462d-8586-cfaafae8f2b1",
    "_count": {
        "releases": 0
    }
```

My Current query is this:

```
 const genresWithReleaseCount = await prisma.genre.findMany({
  select: {
    name: true,
    id: true,
    _count: { select: { releases: { where: { isDeployed: true } } } },
  },
  where: {
    name: { startsWith: "pop", mode: "insensitive" },
  },
  orderBy: { name: "asc" },
  take: 100,
  skip: 0,
});
```

The problem is:

I would like to order by release count first, and then by name: 'asc'

Been stuck on this for a long time help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Modified your code

```js
const genresWithReleaseCount = await prisma.genre.findMany({
    include:{
      _count:{
        select:{
          releases: { where: { isDeployed: false } } 
        }
      }
    },
    where: {
      name: { startsWith: "pop", mode: "insensitive" },
    },
    orderBy: [
      {
        releases: {
          _count: 'asc'
        }
      },
      {
        name: 'asc',
      },
    ],
    take: 100,
    skip: 0,
  });
```

To order by multiple fields, you need to pass an array as shown in the code. See this section of the docs on [sorting with a set of fields](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/filtering-and-sorting#sorting)

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: It is not supported.

---

Existing answers describe situations, where you apply many conditions to sort. This question is about ordering by the filtered result of relation join.

Official docs do not mention it: https://www.prisma.io/docs/orm/prisma-client/queries/filtering-and-sorting#sort-by-relation

There is open Github issue about this problem: https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/20838

It seems to be unsupported now. You have to write rawQuery.